# Quebra de linha com tag <br> causa espaçamento no PDF Gerado

Tags: java, html, pdf, css

Ao converter o html em pdf usando flying saucer em java, no arquivo pdf ocorre a seguinte falha; Um espaçamento entre as ultimas frases, antes da quebra de linha do parágrafo. Isto passa a impressão que o pdf ao ser gerado esteja usando o alinhamento fully justify por default ou invés do justify.

Alguém conheceria uma solução viável para esse problema?

[image: Imagem de Arquivo PDF]

Código Html Convertido.

```
<div style="clear:both;">                                                                    <span> 
<p align="justify" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;padding-   top:5px;"> 1.O EMITENTE promete pagar por esta CÉDULA DE CRÉDITO BANCÁRIO ("Cédula") Ã , Financiamento e Investimento, instituição financeira com sede na Cidade de São Paulo, Estado de São Paulo, na Rua Amazonas da Silva, nº 27, Vila Guilherme, , inscrito no, doravante denominada, ou Ã  ordem desta , em moeda corrente, o valor certo, líquido e exigível correspondente ao Valor do Financiamento mencionado no item 2.3 do Quadro II, acrescido dos juros,encargos e demais despesas previstas nesta Cédula.
<br> 2. Autorizo o envio de mensagens curtas (Torpedo/SMS),para o número de telefone celular indicado no Quadro I,contendo informações relativas aos produtos, serviços, promoções e novidades da e dasdemais empresas integrantes do conglomerado  , desde que isento de qualquer cobrança.Ficará sob a minha responsabilidade comunicar Ã Central de Atendimento qualquer alteração do número do telefone celular cadastrado, sendo o único responsável pelos prejuízos ou qualquer dano ocorrido ou causado em decorrência da omissão ou não veracidade das informações prestadas à .Tenho conhecimento de que a não se responsabiliza pelo não recebimento ou atraso no envio das mensagens parao telefone celular cadastrado. - Rubrica do EMITENTE_____________________________.
<br> 3.Consideram-se incorporadas a esta Cédula os Termos e Condições da Cédula de Crédito Bancário,registrado no 10º Oficial de Registro de Títulos e Documentos de São Paulo sob o , em 10/05/2010,do qual o EMITENTE declara ter conhecimento, neste ato.<br>
<br> Esta Cédula é emitida em 2 via(s), sendo    somente a via da negociável.
</p> 
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tag `<br/>` faz uma quebra de linha e não uma quebra de parágrafo, o que deve ser feito com `<p>`.

Tente o seguinte código:

```
<div style="clear:both;">                                                                    <span> 
<p align="justify" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;padding-   top:5px;"> 1.O EMITENTE promete pagar por esta CÉDULA DE CRÉDITO BANCÁRIO ("Cédula") Ã , Financiamento e Investimento, instituição financeira com sede na Cidade de São Paulo, Estado de São Paulo, na Rua Amazonas da Silva, nº 27, Vila Guilherme, , inscrito no, doravante denominada, ou Ã  ordem desta , em moeda corrente, o valor certo, líquido e exigível correspondente ao Valor do Financiamento mencionado no item 2.3 do Quadro II, acrescido dos juros,encargos e demais despesas previstas nesta Cédula.</p>
<p> 2. Autorizo o envio de mensagens curtas (Torpedo/SMS),para o número de telefone celular indicado no Quadro I,contendo informações relativas aos produtos, serviços, promoções e novidades da e dasdemais empresas integrantes do conglomerado  , desde que isento de qualquer cobrança.Ficará sob a minha responsabilidade comunicar Ã Central de Atendimento qualquer alteração do número do telefone celular cadastrado, sendo o único responsável pelos prejuízos ou qualquer dano ocorrido ou causado em decorrência da omissão ou não veracidade das informações prestadas à .Tenho conhecimento de que a não se responsabiliza pelo não recebimento ou atraso no envio das mensagens parao telefone celular cadastrado. - Rubrica do EMITENTE_____________________________.</p>
<p> 3.Consideram-se incorporadas a esta Cédula os Termos e Condições da Cédula de Crédito Bancário,registrado no 10º Oficial de Registro de Títulos e Documentos de São Paulo sob o , em 10/05/2010,do qual o EMITENTE declara ter conhecimento, neste ato.</p>
<p>Esta Cédula é emitida em 2 via(s), sendo    somente a via da negociável./p> 
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Allan Andrade. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou tentar assim que chegar ao trabalho, retorno com um feedback

Comment: Deu certo o código acima?

Comment: tive que manter com o <br>, pois não poderia ter um espaço entre os parágrafos. Então nas linhas que ocorria o espaçamento desnecessário coloquei um <span style ="text-align = left"></span> e ao gerar o PDF ficou alinhado como eu queria. Obrigado pelo auxílio. @AllanAndrade